# Get enum name in Python without class name

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I would like to create my own enum. This will have names but no values.
When calling this enum it should always return the name.

```
from enum import Enum

class myEnum(Enum):
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

my_enum = myEnum('enum', ['a', 'b'])
```

With:

```
print(my_enum.a)
```

it will returns a. That's ok.

But using this in a class:

```
class T():
    def do_something(self):
        print(my_enum.a)
```

With:

```
T().do_something()
```

will return enum.a

Goal is this will always return a.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If *When calling this enum it should always return the name* means when a `string` is required then you can add this method to the `myEnum` class:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```