# Python pandas sort dataframe by enum class values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting, enums, categorical-data

If I have enum class:

```
from enum import Enum
class Colors(Enum):
    RED = 1
    ORANGE = 2
    GREEN = 3
```

And if I have a dataframe whose one column is color (it can be in lowercase to):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'X':['A', 'B', 'C', 'A'], 'color' : ['GREEN', 'RED', 'ORANGE', 'ORANGE']})
>>> df
   X   color
0  A   GREEN
1  B     RED
2  C  ORANGE
3  A  ORANGE
```

How to make color column as categorical type respecting Color class values, and sort the dataframe by "color" and "X" (ascending)?

For example, the dataframe above should be sorted as:

```
X, color
--------
B, RED
A, ORANGE
C, ORANGE
A, GREEN
```

Answer (score 9):

Combination of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39223389/13386979) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55612393/13386979): use a `pd.Categorical` to sort by the `Colors` class (with a slight edit to change its `str`):

```
from enum import Enum
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'X':['A', 'B', 'C', 'A'], 'color' : ['GREEN', 'RED', 'ORANGE', 'ORANGE']})

class Colors(Enum):
    RED = 1
    ORANGE = 2
    GREEN = 3
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

df['color'] = pd.Categorical(df['color'], [str(i) for i in Colors], ordered=True)
df = df.sort_values(['color','X'])
```

Result:

```
   X   color
1  B     RED
3  A  ORANGE
2  C  ORANGE
0  A   GREEN
```

Comment: Both answers are good, but I believe that this one is more pythonic. Thank you all.

Answer (score 5):

Use `getattr`:

```
df["value"] = df["color"].apply(lambda x: getattr(Colors, x).value)
df.sort_values(by=['value',"X"])
```

Output:

```
    X   color   value
1   B   RED     1
3   A   ORANGE  2
2   C   ORANGE  2
0   A   GREEN   3
```

In one line (and without creation of value column):

```
df.iloc[pd.concat([df["X"], df["color"].apply(lambda x: getattr(Colors, x))], axis=1).sort_values(by=['color',"X"]).index]
```

Output:

```
    X   color
1   B   RED
3   A   ORANGE
2   C   ORANGE
0   A   GREEN
```

Comment: I would also consider changing `Colors(Enum)` to `Colors(IntEnum)` because it can be used within a sort-function without calling to `value` of the attribute.

Comment: OP also wanted sorting on `X`, this is easily added to the `by` of `sort_values` in your first method but I couldn't figure how to do so on your second

Comment: @Tom you are right, I missed that. Thanks! I don't think is possible to use argsort in this case then.